# Query dates that is lesser or equal to set of date ranges

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I query dates that is lesser than or equal to more than one dates with single sql query?

I need to find

```
date <= ('29-05-2018', '30-05-2018', '31-05-2018')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?  Why did you tag with both (this may lead to confusion for the people trying to answer your question) ?

Answer (score 7):

The most restrictive date, i.e. the earliest one, will determine the filtering, since any dates greater than this would be less restrictive.  So, an alternative to using `ALL` would be to use `LEAST`:

```
WHERE date <= LEAST('2018-05-29', '2018-05-30', '2018-05-31')
```

EDIT (by Gordon):

In Oracle, this would be:

```
WHERE date <= LEAST(DATE '2018-05-29', DATE '2018-05-30', DATE '2018-05-31')
```

Comment: In Oracle, you want to use the `DATE` keyword before each constant.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`ALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions002.htm#SQLRF52107):

> Compares a value to every value in a list or returned by a query. Must be preceded by =, !=, >, <, <=, >=. **Can be followed by any expression or subquery that returns one or more values.**

```
date <= ALL('29-05-2018', '30-05-2018', '31-05-2018');
```

---

> *Is it possible to have hardcoded dates in the sub query for ALL operator?*

Yes it is possible:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab_name
WHERE date <= ALL (SELECT some_date_column
                   FROM tab_name_2
                   WHERE ...);

<=>
SELECT *
FROM tab_name
WHERE date <= (SELECT MIN(some_date_column)
               FROM tab_name_2
               WHERE ...);
```

---

> *I don't have have those dates in the table. I just want to find out the dates which lies from today to (today + 30 days)*

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE date BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 30; -- Oracle
```

Comment: Is it possible to have hardcoded dates in the sub query for ALL operator. I am getting Syntax error (comma) in query expression?

Comment: I don't have have those dates in the table. I just want to find out the dates which lies from today to (today + 30 days)

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I just want to find out the records which may start date today or lesser than today likewise for 30 days.

Comment: For example I have records with start_date (28-05-2018, 29-05-2018, 30-05-2018, 18-06-2018). I want to get records with these start_date (29-05-2018, 30-05-2018, 18-06-2018).